# Reset execution context of method from Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have existing service and need to cover it with unit-tests.
Can't cope with following case:

```
const exampleVariable = 'test';

export class Class {
  testMethod() {
    if (!exampleVariable ) {
      throw Error('There is no exampleVariable!');
    }
  }
}
```

How I could change value of 'exampleVariable' to reach the case when we have an error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to unit test. In this implementation, the class method relies on the outside state (the value of exampleVariable) to do its job. Instead, it is better to pass this data as a method argument:

```js
export class Class {

  testMethod(exampleVariable) {

    if (!exampleVariable) {
      throw new Error('There is no exampleVariable!');
    }

  }

}
```

The test would look something like this:

```js
let myClass = new Class();

expect(myClass.testMethod(false)).toThrow(new Error('There is no exampleVariable!'))
```

Comment: agree with you. Thanks!